# Why is my HTML document always loading the last occurrence of my two external stylesheets?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to use Media Queries for Responsive Web Design. For the beginning I want to have two different CSS files if the width is higher than 900px or below 900px.

This is how I integrated the external stylesheets:

```
<link id="Min900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Min900/schwarz.css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" />
<link id="Max899" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Max899/schwarz.css" media="screen and (max-width: 899px)" />
```

The funny thing is the last specified external stylesheet is loaded. If I switch the order of both, I get the other stylesheet working.

But they should change depending on the width of the browser.

Comment: If you try renaming one CSS file does the problem resolve itself?

Comment: Having multiple stylesheet calls is a horrible idea. If you are trying to separate your CSS into multiple files for ease when developing, then I'd suggest doing that only for your development environment, and then compiling and minifying for production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! After renaiming I got no problem anymore. I used the same name for a function in javascript.

Btw how can i accept an comment as answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to combine these two style sheets into one file. You're going to introduce an extra html request doing it your way, which will slow down your site. Also, the reason the last one is loading is because they are named the same thing, so the browser is updating the css file, even though they're coming from two different paths. Try renaming one if you don't want to combine them.

Comment: I renamed the files, indeed that solved my problem.

But the reason for 2 external stylesheets is to use different files for different widths of the clients browser.

Comment: But you can do those more efficiently with media queries in a single CSS file. For example, at the end of your style sheet: @media (max-width:899px) { /*all your code from your 899 file*/} Also, if my answer worked for you, please remember to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh okey, don't know that. Than thats indeed a better solution, thanks!